# Adding index failed.. now can't view or edit table

Tags: mysql

I was adding an index on a column and the server timed out. Now all other tables in the database work fine, but I am unable to access the table I was adding an index on. It does not allow me to delete its contents or the table. It just hangs while running the queries and nothing happens.

Any ideas on a possible solution?

MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `REPAIR TABLE` command. Details at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: @krio: Try it better. What was the output from the `REPAIR` attempt? If it fails, you may have completely ruined your table. It should probably work though. You need to give more information.

Comment: Thats the issue. I get NO information back. Any attempt to run any type of command on the table just sits and hangs. NO response. I wish I knew a way to "Try it better." because I would. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The repair my take a while, particularly if there is alot of data and it is rebuilding indexes. After you run `repair table [tablename]` just leave it for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've let it sit for about two hours now. Table is about 70k rows so hopefully this will do it